# How do I get to "Private Sub" for ifthen statements... in Visual Express 2010? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, private, visual-c++-2010-express

I was watching a video on "programming the meaning of life" and I got stumped when he hit an event and it went directly to this place that starts "Private Sub" and ends in "Sub End" [or something like that]. I am a complete n00b trying to learn c++ in my free time. Halp? c:

Comment: Are you sure that was C++ code you were seeing? Private Sub and End Sub sounds like VB code to me

Comment: They are.  You watched the wrong video.

Comment: Bahahaha, thanks a lot. I didn't even think of my own stupidity. XD

Comment: Can anyone direct me to a "Meaning of Life" tutorial for visual studio? :s

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a "meaning of life" tutorial for VC++. This looks like something pretty basic, create a dialog, add a button on it, add a handler for the button and display a message when clicking the button. However, to get the same effect either in VB, or VC# or VC++ just double click the button and the IDE will add the event handler.